# Convert this list from stdin into dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and need help with converting a list "lis" into a dictionary "dic". The list is generated by reading lines from stdin as follows-

```
lis = sys.stdin.readlines()

['San Jose\t200.82\n', 'California\t115.15\n', 'San Jose\t20.20\n', 'Texas\t300.10\n', 'San Jose\t100.50\n']
```

I have done the following to convert an item in list into key,value but dont know how to store this in a dictionary.

```
for item in lis:
    k,v1 = item.split('\t')
    v = float(v1)
    print k,v
```

I would like to store this in a dictionary as follows

```
{'San Jose':200.82, 'California':115.15 .....etc}
```

Could you please show me how to do this efficiently? Later on I would like to load this dictionary into Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Just add something like `your_dictionary[k] = v` to the loop?

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
dic = {} 
for k,v in [e.strip().split("\t") for e in lis]:
    dic[k] = v
#{'San Jose': '100.50', 'California': '115.15', 'Texas': '300.10'}
```

Or more succinctly -

```
dic = {k:v for k,v in [e.strip().split("\t") for e in lis]}
```

If you don't want to overwrite previous values -

```
dic = {} 
for k,v in [e.strip().split("\t") for e in lis]:
    if k not in dic:
        dic[k] = v
```

If you want to have multiple values for the same key.

```
dic = {}
for k,v in [e.strip().split("\t") for e in lis]:
    if k not in dic:
        dic[k] = [v]
    else:
        dic[k].append(v)

'''
Output of the Dictionary.
{
    'San Jose': ['200.82', '20.20', '100.50'],
    'California': ['115.15'],
    'Texas': ['300.10']
}
'''
```

Comment: A `defaultdict(list)` would work better for your last example

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
dic = {}
for item in lis:
    k,v1 = item.split('\t')
    v = float(v1)
    print k,v
    dic[k] = v
```

Of course, you could simplify this with a comprehension:

```
dic = {item.split('\t')[0]:float(item.split('\t')[1]) for item in lis}
```

It seems that you want multiple values associated with each key. For that, use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(list)
for item in lis:
    k,v1 = item.split('\t')
    v = float(v1)
    print k,v
    dic[k].append(v)
```

Of course, you could just do the heavy-lifting yourself:

```
dic = {}
for item in lis:
    k,v1 = item.split('\t')
    v = float(v1)
    print k,v
    if k not in dic:
        dic[k] = []
    dic[k].append(v)
```

Comment: great suggestions but it will overwrite previous key,value in the dictionary.

Comment: @user3267989 That statement indicates that you don't understand how `dict`s work.  A `dict` can only have one instance of a given key at a time.  It is *impossible* to have all three 'San Jose' values in your dict at once (with out storing the data as a list instead of a float).

Comment: @user3267989 If you could have multiple 'San Jose' keys at once, what would `dic['San Jose']` return?